# Extract and Join Text in Nested Parentheses

Tags: python

I have strings that contain text in parentheses and nested parentheses like this:

```
(Order Filled (today))
```

I want to extract the text to give the following result:

```
Order Filled today
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What happens if the parentheses do not match in pairs?

Comment: Just use twice the `replace` method of the string: `s.replace('(','').replace(')','')`

Comment: *Most efficient way* in therms of performance or development time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If your goal is just to remove all parentheses, then you can use replace function

```py
string = '(Order Filled (today))'
string.replace('(','').replace(')','')
```

---

#### Update: Removing only those parentheses that has endings.

I know you asked for `most efficient way` but, when you use `replace` function, that will also remove the `non nested parentheses`, so I have a function that removes only nested parentheses:

```py
def markup(message):
    msg = message
    result = ""
    markups = "()"
    num = 0

    # Check if the parentheses
    def has_ending(_str, i, msg):
        if _str == "(":
            return ")" in msg[i+1:]
        elif _str == ")":
            return False
        else:
            return False
  
    for i in range(len(msg)) :
        t = msg[i]
        s = t

        # if the char is '(' or ')'
        if t in markups:
            if has_ending(t, i, msg) and num%2 == 0 :
                s = ""
                num += 1 
            elif t == ")" and num%2 == 1 :
                s = ""
                num += 1 
        # else
        else :
            s = t
        result += s
    return result

print(markup('Hello )(O) (O)( (O)'))
# prints 'Hello )O O (O'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string = '(Order Filled (today))'

x = ''.join(x for x in string if x not in '()')
```

i prefer this as it extends more easily if you wish to remove more characters

Comment: You don't have to use list. A string consisting of the unwanted characters is enough. In your example you can replace `['(',')']` with `'()'`. This should also take a little bit less memory.

Comment: this is true and works. in my head i was just thinking of a list. will amend.